# Is the Bellman backup unbiased?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, proofs, temporal-difference-methods, bias

This is comes from cs285 2023Fall hw3.
[image]

In my opinion, if $\hat{Q}$ is unbiased estimate of $Q$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}_{D \sim P}[B_{D}\hat{Q} - B_{D}Q]
&= \mathbb{E}_{D \sim P}[r(s,a) + \gamma max_{a'}\hat{Q}(s', a') - r(s,a) - \gamma max_{a'}Q(s', a')]\\
&=\mathbb{E}_{D \sim P}[\gamma max_{a'}\hat{Q}(s', a')- \gamma max_{a'}Q(s', a')]\\
&= 0
\end{align}$$
So $\hat{Q}$ is unbiased estimate of $Q$ and the answer is yes.
Is this right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your provided definition of unbiased estimator at each input data, and since $\hat{Q}$ is an unbiased estimator for the true action value $Q$ at each state-action input pair, applying Bellman backup operator defined in your reference involving a max operator would result in biased $B\hat{Q}$ not converging to $BQ$ in expectation at each state-action input pair. The distribution of the maximum of $n$ independent i.i.d. random variables doesn't necessarily follow the same distribution, it may follow [Gumbel distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution) for example, which may not have same expectation as the original distribution, as pointed out by another answer.

Of course in reality TD off-policy Q-learning cannot ensure there always exists such an unbiased $\hat{Q}$ estimator at each state-action input.

Answer (score 3):

No, $B\hat{Q}$ is not an unbiased estimator. Say that $Q(s, a) = 0$, and $\hat{Q}(s, a) \sim N(0, 1)$. Then $E[max_a \space Q(s, a)] = 0$, but $E[max_a \space \hat{Q}(s, a)] > 0$ (approximately 1.5387 if you have 10 different actions).